# How to play fullscreen video on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android

I developed an app that plays a video on fullscreen mode, it works fine on mobile phones but when I tested it on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running on Honeycomb 3.1 it seems the taskbar still stays on the bottom.

I tried running some apps like angry birds but still it can't run on fullscreen mode, the taskbar stays on the bottom still. Running the youtube app just makes taskbar into black and the screen mode stays the same.

Is this a limitation on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1? or this a standard on all HoneyComb?

Thanks Android Gurus =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom bar can never go away on Honeycomb, because since tablets do not have hardware home or back buttons, the only way for the user to exit your app is to use the bottom status bar. If it were hideable, they would be stuck in your app, and that wouldn't be a good user experience.

Comment: I don't fully agree with this answer: if you test the Gallery or YouTube app you can see that the controls as well as the clock are just a dimmed gray dot instead of the full buttons so they provide a better experience for full screen video. At least that's what I see on an Asus Transfomer

Comment: Yup, but you can't get rid of the bar, but you can "dim" it, as BrainCrash said, using setSystemUiVisibility(int).

Answer (score 1):

AmandeepGrewal is correct, but you should also be able to "dim" the bar with:
    [setSystemUiVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29).

You can see if this is of any help:

```
ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    //mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(visibility);
    if (visibility == View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE) {
        actionBar.show();
    } else {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work, can you check if there is something wrong with my code? thanks.
The taskbar is still visible.

VideoView mvideo;
mvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
mvideo.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);

Comment: I've updated the answer with some code, check if it helps you.

Comment: Samsung has done a customization of the default Honeycomb graphics as part of their own TouchWiz UI. On vanilla Honeycomb, the bottom bar fades out in dimmed mode, only leaving fuzzy shadows of system buttons; the Samsung counterpart does the same except the 1-pixel bevel they added which stays "on". This makes a disturbing 1px frame in place of the bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently, it is possible for the taskbar to be hidden completely on **Honeycomb 3.2** because I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Plus 7.0, and when the Kindle app runs, the taskbar completely disappears.  If one taps the screen anywhere in the Kindle app, the taskbar pops back up.

Presumably, any app could be written or modified to allow this capability.